# Any better way to Return 1 value for multiple row in case when by window Function?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, case-when

data like this:

```
timestamp id  roas 
day 5     id1  1.3
day 4     id1  2.1
day 3     id1  1.9
day 2     id1  1.4
day 1     id1  3.0
```

I want to get data of the first day when roas < = 1.5 for all row have 'id1' that is `day 2`, desired result:

```
timestamp id  roas  min_date
day 5     id1  1.3  day 2
day 4     id1  2.1  day 2
day 3     id1  1.9  day 2
day 2     id1  1.4  day 2
day 1     id1  3.0  day 2
```

Currently, I use:

```
, t2 as (select *, case when roas < = 1.5 then timestamp else null end as day_roas from t1)
select *, min(day_roas) over (partition by id) as min_date
from t2
```

Comment: Notice that just `min(CASE WHEN roas <= 1.5 THEN timestamp END)` would work as well, no need for the extra `t2` CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`FILTER` clause with your window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS):

```
SELECT *, min(timestamp) FILTER (WHERE roas <= 1.5) OVER (PARTITION BY id) FROM t1
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ecf03d0f04ec2ab64bb3bcd7fab5586f))</sup>