# Return 1 specific value to all row using Window Function and Filter

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I need the timestamp satisfy: order_day = '4th' to show in 1 column

data like this called 't1':

```
timestamp id   order_day 
day 9     id1  5th
day 8     id1  4th
day 7     id1  3th
day 6     id1  2th
day 5     id1  1th
```

desired result:

```
timestamp id   order_day  info
day 9     id1  5th        day 8
day 8     id1  4th        day 8
day 7     id1  3rd        day 8
day 6     id1  2nd        day 8
day 5     id1  1st        day 8
```

Currently I use:

```
select *,
min(timestamp) filter (where order_day = '4th') over (partition by id) as info
from t1
```

But I don't want to use `min()` as it's not my purpose, because each `id` there is only 1 `'4th'` for `order_day`, so use `max() or min()` show the same result. Are there any way?

I have asked a question with a little bit same but using `min()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63072200/any-better-way-to-return-1-value-for-multiple-row-in-case-when-by-window-functio)

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `min()` (or `max()`), while it prodices the result you want?

Comment: Because I thought it should have another way for this purpose @GMB

Comment: EX: I use : `(case when order_day = '4th' then timestamp else null end) over (...) ` not work and not use min() : `timestamp filter () over ()` will cause syntax error

Comment: I think the window `min()` (or `max()`) is the best approach here.

Comment: EX: I use : `(case when order_day = '4th' then timestamp else null end) over (...) ` not work and not use min() : `timestamp filter () over ()` will cause syntax error @GMB

Answer (score 1):

you can use correlated sub-query as alternative-

```
select A.*,
(select timestamp from t1 B where B.order_day = '4th' AND B.id = A.id) as info
from t1 A
```

Another alternative is-

```
select A.imestamp,
A.id,
A.order_day,
B.timestamp as info
from t1 A 
inner join (
    select id, timestamp 
    from t1 
    where order_day = '4th'
) B
on A.id = B.id
```

Remember these are just alternative options, you need to select which one suits best for your case.